# Tinymce drop upload image and mobile upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

1.I want to drop image and upload,but I can't do this.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    menubar: false,
    plugins: 'image emoticons',
    toolbar: 'image emoticons',
    forced_root_block: '',
    branding: false,
    statusbar: false,
    image_dimensions: false,
    image_description: false,
    paste_data_images: true,
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('change', function () {
            editor.save();
        });
    },
    images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
        formData.append('test_id', id);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'url.php',
            type: "post",
            data: formData,
            dataType: "text",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data) {
                success(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                console.log(blobInfo);
                console.log(xhr.status);
            }
        });
    },
});
```

2.I want to upload image from mobile.After I click choose image button , I don't get choose image window . How can I do?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `but I can't do this`, why? Any errors in the `console`? Also, can you create a working snippet so we could try to debug it?

Comment: sorry maybe I should say not working.there is no error in console,finally,I make a new window and input to cover this.

Comment: @tuo Did you manage to find a solution for Question 2 regarding image upload on mobile phone?

Comment: I forgive plugins of image , Create a new interface to finish it.